# ftp how can I report progress

Tags: vb.net, winforms

We Have a custom component which downloaded files in a batch but I cant seem to report progress on individual files.

I am able to get to the start file transfer message which his handled by the event handler feed back, but because the download files could be downloading 30 or so files at a time it obviously wont show the next message, so my question is how can I report the progress back of each file via status bar of some description.

```
Event FeedBack(ByVal message As String, ByVal displayToUser As Boolean)

Friend Function DownloadFilesFromFTPsite(ByVal filename() As String) As Boolean

  Dim retVal As Boolean = False
    Dim ftpController As New FTP.DotNet.FtpClient(cfb.FTPHost, cfb.FtpUserName, cfb.FtpPassword)
    WriteToLogAndRaiseFeedback("Starting File Transfer", True)
    Dim ftpResponse() As FTP.DotNet.infoFTPresponse
    ftpResponse = ftpController.DownloadFiles(IIf(cfb.SourceFolder.Trim = "", "/", cfb.SourceFolder), filename, cfb.TargetFolder)
    WriteToLogAndRaiseFeedback("Transfering File " + filename.ToString(), True)


    If Not IsNothing(ftpResponse) AndAlso ftpResponse.Length > 0 Then
        For Each thisResponse As FTP.DotNet.infoFTPresponse In ftpResponse
            If Not IsNothing(thisResponse) _
            AndAlso IsNumeric(thisResponse.statusCode) AndAlso thisResponse.statusCode = 226 Then
                '226 = success
                WriteToLogAndRaiseFeedback("...document downloaded sucessfully", True)
                retVal = True
            ElseIf Not IsNothing(thisResponse) Then
                WriteToLogAndRaiseFeedback("...FAILED to download document: " & thisResponse.statusDescription, True)
                retVal = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Comment: You should take more time writing the question... your whole paragraph is messy and filled with typos etc, and the title should reflect your problem (your question does not seem to relate to a specific .Net version also, since the classes are the same).

Comment: @julealgon I am just saying the .net version to make them aware not to use anything fancy out .net 4.0 and also sorry for the poor grammer and spelling not all of our experts in that field. e.g if they where using some threading that might not be available in 3.5 so it is relevant to mention the version

Comment: Perhaps it would be more clear if you removed the .Net info from the title and explained your limitation on the question itself.

Comment: @julealgon I have deslyixa and that is a very rude thing to say I can program but just cant spell to well !

Comment: @julealgon edits done as suggested

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry about that. It was not my intention to offend you ;)